# SignalR - Authenticating users

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions

I am using the Azure SignalR service. I've set up multiple azure function apps (Node.js) with various end points for users to join specific groups and to broadcast to those users etc.

I couldn't find detailed documentation on how to determine if a user has logged in before establishing a connection to them. On the negotiate endpoint I pass in a userID but this is just a dummy string I've made up for now. I'm trying to find a way to authorize users via a standard cookie login system.

The flow would be
- User is authorized and a cookie is created for a standard session
- Somehow pass this cookie to the SignalR negotiate method to check if user is authorized

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to setup [authentication/authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json) on your function app. The same is covered in the [SignalR Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service?tabs=csharp#authenticated-tokens) as well.

If you are using something like [Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) in front of your function app(s), then you would want to [enable authentication there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad).